# Error: While building wheels for quadprog

Tags: python, anaconda, quadprog

I am using Windows 11 and I am writing this on Anaconda.
I typed in:
`pip install trajectory_planning_helper`

The output I get is:

```
  !!
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Compiling quadprog/quadprog.pyx because it changed.
  [1/1] Cythonizing quadprog/quadprog.pyx
  c:\users\anish\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-78msmrdf\quadprog_5eaf3b92617c445f82aa0fcae5610ae6\.eggs\cython-3.0.2-py3.11-win-amd64.egg\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:384: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: C:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78msmrdf\quadprog_5eaf3b92617c445f82aa0fcae5610ae6\quadprog\quadprog.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'quadprog' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcquadprog/aind.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/aind.obj
  aind.c
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcquadprog/daxpy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/daxpy.obj
  daxpy.c
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcquadprog/ddot.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/ddot.obj
  ddot.c
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcquadprog/dpofa.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/dpofa.obj
  dpofa.c
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcquadprog/dscal.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/dscal.obj
  dscal.c
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcquadprog/f2c_lite.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/f2c_lite.obj
  f2c_lite.c
  quadprog/f2c_lite.c(48): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  quadprog/f2c_lite.c(134): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  quadprog/f2c_lite.c(181): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'integer', possible loss of data
  quadprog/f2c_lite.c(545): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /EHsc /Tpquadprog/quadprog.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/quadprog.obj
  quadprog.cpp
  quadprog/quadprog.cpp(17931): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  quadprog/quadprog.cpp(17932): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  quadprog/quadprog.cpp(18076): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  quadprog/quadprog.cpp(24469): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /EHsc /Tcquadprog/solve.QP.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/solve.QP.obj
  solve.QP.c
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /EHsc /Tcquadprog/util.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/util.obj
  util.c
  creating C:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78msmrdf\quadprog_5eaf3b92617c445f82aa0fcae5610ae6\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\anish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_quadprog build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/aind.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/daxpy.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/ddot.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/dpofa.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/dscal.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/f2c_lite.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/quadprog.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/solve.QP.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog/util.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\quadprog.cp311-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog\quadprog.cp311-win_amd64.lib
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog\quadprog.cp311-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\quadprog\quadprog.cp311-win_amd64.exp
  quadprog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl qpgen2_(double *,double *,int *,int *,double *,double *,double *,double *,double *,int *,int *,int *,int *,int *,int *,double *,int *)" (?qpgen2_@@YAXPEAN0PEAH10000011111101@Z)
    Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
      qpgen2_
  build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\quadprog.cp311-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for quadprog
Running setup.py clean for quadprog
Failed to build quadprog
ERROR: Could not build wheels for quadprog, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I am getting this code from github link about rc cars. The link is here: https://github.com/CL2-UWaterloo/Raceline-Optimization. They also don't have a solution for this.

I installed vscode build tools for C++, but it didn't work. I have not tried uninstalling and reinstalling vs code because that is time-taking. If anyone has other solutions, please tell me.